How to determine the MIME type of a binary file?
Is there a way to determine the MIME type of a binary file ? The file has been uploaded and is stored as a XSTRING variable.
I've looked at:

CL_MIME_REPOSITORY_API
FM RSFO_XSTRING_TO_MIME

None do what I'm looking for.

Which OS?  Because Windows does not have that option (see: Finding a MIME type for a file on windows )

Does this file has a name with a file extension? Maybe the information is attached next to the file: which "system" contains this file? MIME Repository, Content Management software...?

No, there is no way.  As @sandra-rosi comments, I could infer from the file extension, but it's not safe.

With no mime type or file extension available, you will have to actually look at the content of the file and look for any magic strings that tell you what type of file it could be. There are tools and libraries for that which are able to detect a lot of different file types. But I am not aware of any that were ported to ABAP.

A  files "mime type" can be implied in a number of ways.
by its http "content-type" or by its filename extension.
content-type is similar to a filename extension or mimetype and is typically used to determine the application used to process the file.
Another approach is to use Content-Type application/octet-stream and then the filename is part on the Content-Disposition header.
Mimetypes is a term that is a outdated nowadays. Since it is email attachment concept originally. More recently the term Content-Type is used. Since it is part of the HTTP specification.
File Extensions can be converted to Content-Type.
And on PCs file extension have programs associated with them.
So when you have a binary file, it doesnt have a MIMETYPE.
Its filename extension can imply the content type.
it is good practice to store the actually content-type and extension as part of the meta data.
Some extension to content type conversions, in case the helps in understanding.
CASE mime_ext_or_content_type.

      
  WHEN '7z'.  r_content_type =  'application/x-7z-compressed'.

 
  WHEN 'bin'.  r_content_type =  'application/octet-stream'.
  WHEN 'bmp'.  r_content_type =  'image/bmp'.
  WHEN 'csv'.  r_content_type =  'text/csv'.
  WHEN 'doc'.  r_content_type =  'application/msword'.
  WHEN 'docm'.  r_content_type =  'application/vnd.ms-word.document.macroEnabled.12'.
  WHEN 'docx'.  r_content_type =  'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document'.
  WHEN 'dot'.  r_content_type =  'application/msword'.
  WHEN 'dotm'.  r_content_type =  'application/vnd.ms-word.template.macroEnabled.12'.
  WHEN 'dotx'.  r_content_type =  'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.template'.
  WHEN 'dsp'.  r_content_type =  'application/octet-stream'.
  WHEN 'dsw'.  r_content_type =  'text/plain'.
  WHEN 'dtd'.  r_content_type =  'text/xml'.
  ....."a few hundred lines removed....
  WHEN 'xlc'.  r_content_type =  'application/vnd.ms-excel'.
  WHEN 'xld'.  r_content_type =  'application/vnd.ms-excel'.
  WHEN 'xlk'.  r_content_type =  'application/vnd.ms-excel'.
  WHEN 'xll'.  r_content_type =  'application/vnd.ms-excel'.
  WHEN 'xlm'.  r_content_type =  'application/vnd.ms-excel'.
  WHEN 'xls'.  r_content_type =  'application/vnd.ms-excel'.
  WHEN 'xlsb'.  r_content_type =  'application/vnd.ms-excel.sheet.binary.macroEnabled.12'.
  WHEN 'xlsm'.  r_content_type =  'application/vnd.ms-excel.sheet.macroEnabled.12'.
  WHEN 'xlsx'.  r_content_type =  'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'.

  WHEN 'xslt'.  r_content_type =  'text/xml'.
  WHEN 'xsn'.  r_content_type =  'application/octet-stream'.
  WHEN 'xss'.  r_content_type =  'application/xml'.
  WHEN 'xtp'.  r_content_type =  'application/octet-stream'.
  WHEN 'xwd'.  r_content_type =  'image/x-xwindowdump'.
  WHEN 'z'.  r_content_type =  'application/x-compress'.
  WHEN 'zip'.  r_content_type =  'application/x-zip-compressed'.


  WHEN OTHERS.
    " cant help
    r_content_type = mime_ext_or_content_type.
ENDCASE.
ENDMETHOD.


Id like to know why you find the above unhelpful / wrong.

probably because you didn't explain how one should determine mime_ext_or_content_type
